# Probability Exercise 1.4.3 in Grimmett and Stirzaker

Tags: probability

I am having trouble understanding the highlighted solution to the following exercise 1.4.3 in Grimmet and Stirzaker :

[image]

[image]

Why is this ?

in (i) the space was partitioned by the type of coin, so that is fine.

In (iii)  there seems to be some partitioning too, but I don't understand how it is done.

I can recover the same answer by a different (simpler?) method, but I would still be interested in how the authors wrote down their solution

Mine is as follows:

$P(H_l^2 | H_u^1) = P(H_l^2 \cap H_u^1) / P(H_u^1)$

Now from a calculation similar to (i) $P(H_u^1) = 3/5$

Also $P(H_l^2 \cap H_u^1) = P(H_l^2 \cap H_u^1 | M) P(M) + P(H_l^2 \cap H_u^1 | N) P(N) + P(H_l^2 \cap H_u^1 | R) P(R) = [ \frac{1}{1} \times \frac{1}{1} ] \times \frac{2}{5} + [ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} ] \times \frac{2}{5} + 0 \times \frac{1}{5} $ (because the 2 tosses of the coin are independent)

hence $P(H_l^2 | H_u^1)  = \frac {[ \frac{1}{1} \times \frac{1}{1} ] \times \frac{2}{5} + [ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} ] \times \frac{2}{5} + 0 \times \frac{1}{5}} {\frac{3}{5}}  = \frac{2}{5} \times \frac{5}{3} + [ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} ] \times \frac{2}{5} \times \frac{5}{3} = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} = 5/6 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partitioning is still by the type of coin.

\begin{align}
P(H_1^2|H_u^1)&= P(H_1^2|M,H_u^1)P(M|H_u^1) + P(H_1^2|N,H_u^1)P(N|H_u^1) \\
&=1 \cdot P(M|H_u^1) + \frac12 \cdot P(N|H_u^1) \\
\end{align}

Also, note that

$$P(M|H_u^1)=P(H_l^1|H_u^1)$$

Since if the upper side is known to be head, the event that it is a coin with $2$ heads is equal to the event that the lower side is head.

\begin{align}P(N|H_u^1)=1-P(M|H_u^1)-P(R|H_u^1)=1-P(M|H_u^1)-0=1-P(H_l^1|H_u^1) \end{align}

Comment: 2 quick questions: #1 when people write $P(A|B,C)$ is it  really $P(A|B \cap C)$ ? #2 Is it the case that in general $ P(A|B) = P(A| U_1 \cap B) P(U_1 | B) + P(A| U_2 \cap B) P(U_2 | B) $ for a partition $U_1,U_2$ ?

Comment: yes to both questions.

Comment: many thanks !!!